# Generate random tokens (unique id's) for users in a table in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a table in sql server and fill it up with data (people's info). The goal is to get every person a unique ID in the first row which has to start with fixed alphabets `GM` followed by `A-Z` or `2-9` numeric , initial of First name, Initial of Last name and `A-Z` or `2-9`.

Comment: Why not just generate uniqueidentifiers with `NEWID()`, and prefix the `GM` to the beginning?

Comment: the requirement was very specific to include this , i said we can use newid() but they are not sure about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: With the logic you are requesting i don't think you can produce Unique value without check that the table doesn't contains the generated value, the only way is to use `NEWID()` function that generate a GUID, else i think that there is always a duplication risk*

I don't know if this is the best way to do that, but i can say that it gives the expected output. You can create this function and use it to generate the identifier:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.CreateIdentifier
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @Firstname varchar(255),
    @Lastname varchar(255),
    @random1 decimal(18,10) ,
    @random2 decimal(18,10)
)
RETURNS varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @S VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @S1 VARCHAR(1)
    DECLARE @S2 VARCHAR(1)
    DECLARE @len INT
    DECLARE @Random1Fixed INT
    DECLARE @Random2Fixed INT

    declare @alphabet varchar(36) = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789'



    SET @alphabet = REPLACE(@alphabet,LEFT(@Lastname,1),'')
    SET @alphabet = REPLACE(@alphabet,LEFT(@Firstname,1),'')

    SELECT @len = len(@alphabet)
    SET @Random1Fixed = ROUND(((@len - 1 -1) * @random1 + 1), 0)
    SET @Random2Fixed = ROUND(((@len - 1 -1) * @random2 + 1), 0)


    SET @S1 = substring(@alphabet, convert(int, @Random1Fixed ), 1)
    SET @S2 = substring(@alphabet, convert(int, @Random2Fixed), 1)

    SET @S = 'GM' + @S1 + LEFT(@Firstname,1) + LEFT(@Lastname,1) + @S2
    RETURN @S

END
```

And you can use it as the following

```
SELECT dbo.CreateIdentifier('John','Wills',RAND(),RAND())
```

I am passing `RAND()` as parameter because it cannot be used within a function

Comment: i cant use the NEWID() as they are not sure about it and they want to be very specific. Can i add a fixed parameter to the beginning of this function to start with 'GM' ?

Comment: in your question you mentioned that the identifier starts with `initial of First name, Initial of Last name`? else i will update the answer

Comment: @Nani i updated my answer to add another function check it out

Comment: how can i use this to the data thats already in the table ? will i be able to generate the unique code based on this requirement ?

Comment: @Nani You can do this using an `UPDATE` query: `UPDATE TABLE1 SET [ID_Field] = dbo.CreateIdentifier(RAND(),RAND())` *(if you choose the second function i provided)*, or `UPDATE TABLE1 SET [ID_Field] = dbo.CreateIdentifier([FirstName],[Lastname],RAND(),RAND())` *(for the first function)* but it is not guaranteed that there is no duplicates

Comment: @Nani because this function has some weakness, because it is generating random value and it is not generated on some unique values. But anyway this is what you are asking for

Comment: i modified the query a little bit and it ran fine , but i noticed that the letters before FName Lname and after that are repeating the same ex : GMPDDP , GMBDDB . how should i modify this to get two random things in this places.  DD is the fname and lname of the person.

Comment: @Nani oh now i get it. i was misunderstanding what you aims to. check my answer update

Comment: It worked , thank you . but i noticed that some times i have the values like GMDD7
GM2DD and also when i try to use the update statement its kind of updating the entire table rather than just one i need to, any way around it.

Comment: This issue is caused by RAND() because it must be greater than `0` and smaller than `@alphabet` variable length. i am trying to fix it

Comment: i am trying to update the column in the table with this function but when i do it it kind of update all the column and each time i have to use 'where' clause for it to not to do it. Is there any way to get over this and will be possible for this function to check the existing values in the column and not create a duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ambiguities in your question, but hopefully by reading through this you will be able to fill in the blanks.

One question you may want to ask is if you truly want to go within the ID constraints you've provided. It may make a lot more sense to use an identity column (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property).

The exact syntax depends on which dialect of SQL you're working with. Take a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

For MS SQL server it would look something like this:

```
create table User (
   [UserID] int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   [FirstName] varchar(50) not null,
   [LastName] varchar(50) not null
)
```

Let's say you populated this table with a few entries. If for some arbitrary requirement you needed "GM" in the front and the user's initials at the end, you could do something like:

```
select 'GM'+UserID+'substring(FirstName,0,1)+substring(LastName,0,1) from User
```

To answer your question more directly, it appears that you are asking for each user to have an ID that looks like `GM[A-Z or 2-9][FirstInitial][LastInitial][A-Z or 2-9)]`

This setup will give you a lot more of a headache, but it's certainly doable. Note that, as I understand your request, having just one character of A-Z/0-9 after GM and another character after the initials will give you a very limited # of possible unique ID's.

You did not give a max ID character length, so I'm assuming the entire length is fixed at 6 characters ("G","M","A-Z/2-9","F","L","A-Z/2-9"). If I'm misunderstanding you then it will definitely change the answer but hopefully this is still useful.

You could create a User table and a table that holds your possible characters like this:

```
create table UserTable  (
    ID varchar(50),
    FirstName varchar(50),
    LastName varchar(50)
)

create table PChars (
    Possibility varchar(1)
)

insert into PChars (Possibility) values
('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('G'),('H'),('I'),('J'),('K'),('L'),('M'),('N'),('O'),('P'),('Q'),('R'),('S'),('T'),('U'),('V'),('W'),('X'),('Y'),('Z'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7'),('8'),('9')
```

Then you can run the following over and over, note that John and Jane will never have the same ID even though they have the same initials. The `while` clause forbids it.

Also note that eventually this will break. If enough people with the same initials were in the table, the while clause could turn into an infinite loop. **That's why this is kind of a bad idea!!!**

```
delete UserTable /*this is just here so you can run this code over and over*/

/*John Doe*/
declare @FirstName varchar(50) = 'John'
declare @LastName varchar(50) = 'Doe'
declare @newID varchar(50) = ''
while(@newID = '' or @newID in (select distinct ID from UserTable))
  begin
    select @newID = 'GM'+(select top 1 Possibility from PChars order by newid())+substring(@FirstName,1,1)+substring(@LastName,1,1)+(select top 1 Possibility from PChars order by newid())
  end
insert into UserTable select @newID,@FirstName,@LastName

/*Jane Doe*/
select @FirstName = 'Jane'
select @LastName = 'Doe'
select @newID = ''
while(@newID = '' or @newID in (select distinct ID from UserTable))
  begin
    select @newID = 'GM'+(select top 1 Possibility from PChars order by newid())+substring(@FirstName,1,1)+substring(@LastName,1,1)+(select top 1 Possibility from PChars order by newid())
  end
insert into UserTable select @newID,@FirstName,@LastName

select * from UserTable
```

Here is some sample output:

```
+--------+-----------+----------+
|   ID   | FirstName | LastName |
+--------+-----------+----------+
| GMOJDF | John      | Doe      |
| GM2JDD | Jane      | Doe      |
+--------+-----------+----------+
```

So again, I feel like I am somewhat misinterpreting your question, but I think this gives you a good launching point.

Comment: what u said is absolutely correct , now i ran into a problem that i need to keep this unique id for the data thats already in the table. i am not sure how to approach this situation now. can u help

Comment: Exact plan depends on whether you're determining your own ID or you want the ID to be incremented automatically in an IDENTITY clolumn, but here are some helpful articles:

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/how-to-insert-values-into-an-identity-column-in-sql-server

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

You may need to copy the old data out to a separate table then re-insert it once the identity column is there.

Comment: I mean to also include this link in the above comment: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/how-to-insert-values-into-an-identity-column-in-sql-server